# $5^n$ is relatively prime with 13, n in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, coprime

$5^n$ is prime with 13, n in $\mathbb{N}$?

I have proved that $5^{n+4}-5^n \equiv$ 0(mod 13)
. So $5^n(5^4-1) \equiv$ 0(mod 13)

Now Im stuck on how to prove that $5^n$ is relatively prime with 13

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124387/discussion-on-question-by-malek-gara-hellal-5n-is-relatively-prime-with-13-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show, that $13$ doesn't divide $5^n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let us assume, that $13$ does divide $5^n$. Therefore, $13$ is a factor of $5^n$. But as 13 is prime and $5$ is the only prime-factor of $5^n$, $13$ cannot divide $5^n$ by the uniqueness of the prime decomposition.

Comment: Please read the question body (and comments) before attempting to answer questions that are not clear.

Comment: Thank you!!
This answers it.

Comment: @BillDubuque, He actually answered my question

Comment: Not if this was an exercise intended to give an *inductive* proof of the sort that you embarked upon in the question body. That's why I sought further context from you. This helps us to determine what method of proof the exercise is trying to steer you towards. It may well not be the above hinted method (esp. if you don't already have available FTA = Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic or equivalent results).